# libGDX animation on and off

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx

I have this animations that I spawn on the screen every second and remove it every second. The problem is with my calculation. I am using the condtions bellow to spawn every 1.26 seconds:

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - longSpawn > 1260000000) spawnAnt();
```

And this code to remove:

```
if (TimeUtils.nanoTime() - longRemoveAnt > 1000000000) IteratorCircle.remove();
```

Problem is that longRemoveAnt can't be higher or the same as longSpawn, otherwise it won't remove. But more than that, how should I calculate it so the animation will run fully, then will be remove and right after will be spawn again?

Animation code:

```
TextureRegion[] antArr = {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i};
animAnt = new Animation(0.07f, antArr);
animAnt.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP_PINGPONG);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to track elapsed time for each of these (or in the case of my example, countdown-time). If you don't need the precision of nanoseconds, you could use `Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime()` for this, but you can track your own elapsed nanotime like this.

It's not clear from your question exactly what you're doing, so you might have to modify the math below to get it to behave the way you want. I have it spawning an Animation every 1.26 seconds, and removing one every 1.0 seconds, but obviously there will be a problem if you are removing them faster than you are spawning them, which your question implies you are doing.

```
//member variables
static final long SPAWN_TIME_NANOS = 1260000000;
static final long REMOVE_TIME_NANOS = 1000000000;
long timeToNextSpawn = SPAWN_TIME_NANOS;
long timeToRemoveAnt = SPAWN_TIME_NANOS + REMOVE_TIME_NANOS;
long previousTimeNanos= -1;

void spawnAnt(){
    Ant ant = Pools.obtain(Ant.class);
    ant.position.set(...); //however you are doing this.
    ant.age = 0;
}

//In render():
long currentTimeNanos = TimeUtils.nanoTime();
long deltaNanos = (previousNanoTime==-1) ? 0 : currentTimeNanos - previousTimeNanos;
previousTimeNanos = currentTimeNanos;

timeToNextSpawn -= deltaNanos;
while (timeToNextSpawn <= 0){ //using while instead of if in case of long frame
    spawnAnt();
    timeToNextSpawn += SPAWN_TIME_NANOS;
}

timeToRemoveAnt -= deltaNanos;
while (timeToRemoveAnt <= 0){
    IteratorCircle.remove();
    timeToRemoveAnt += REMOVE_TIME_NANOS;
}
```

---

My answer above is based on a literal reading of your question, but it seems to me simpler and less error prone if you have an "Ant" class that can track its own age, like this:

```
public class Ant {
    float age;
    Vector2 position = new Vector2();
}

//member variables
static final float SPAWN_TIME = 1.26f;
static final float REMOVE_TIME = 1.0f;
float timeToNextSpawn = SPAWN_TIME;
LinkedList<Ant> ants = new LinkedList<Ant>(); //LinkedList makes it low cost to remove oldest

void spawnAnt(){
    Ant ant = Pools.obtain(Ant.class); //Use pooling to reduce GC activity
    ant.age = 0;
    ant.position.set(.......);//however you do this
    ants.add(ant);
}

void removeOldestAnt(){
    Ant ant = ants.removeFirst();
    Pools.free(ant);
}

//In render():
float deltaTime = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
for (Ant ant : ants) {
    ant.age += deltaTime;
}
while (ants.size()>0 && ants.getFirst().age >= REMOVE_TIME) 
    removeOldestAnt(); //Assumes ants are ordered by age, which they should be in this code

timeToNextSpawn -= deltaTime;
while (timeToNextSpawn <= 0){ 
    spawnAnt();
    timeToNextSpawn += SPAWN_TIME;
}
```